# Top items of Expandable Listview don't refresh when I make some change of them

Tags: expandablelistview, android

I want to use expandable listview as a main part of a fragment of my app.What I want to achieve is when I click a item of the expandable listview,the item would show something else like a image.However,it gets fine when I click the the 7th,8th,or lager than 8 item of the listview,but the image will not show if I click the top 6 item of the expandable listview. I think it would be something of expandable listview's cache,but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You wrote that caching issue, you should know how to fix it. If you don't know that, consider providing information about what you did (i.e. show us your code)